# Is it possible to retrieve roles from a ServerWebExchange?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I can retrieve a principal name from a `org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange` instance.

```java
exchange.getPrincipal().subscribe(principal -> /* do something with it */);
```

Can I retrieve that principal's roles too? The `java.security.Principal` class (unlike `UserDetails`) only provides a name string (`getName()`)

Use case: suppose I want to write a `GatewayFilter` that takes into account a current user's roles and mutates the exchange:

```java
(exchange, chain) -> /* some filtering logic */
```

Comment: just cast it to a `UserDetails` object

Comment: @Toerktumlare You are right. Only in my case it's `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`

Answer (score 0):

I casted it to `Authentication`. In my case, the principal was in fact a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`, i.e. an `Authentication` subtype

```java
((Authentication) principal).getAuthorities()
```